# How to get all values of a repeated property in a query with a projection on GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a ndb model which has a ComputedProperty that lists multiple values.

```
sku_name = ndb.ComputedProperty(lambda self: makekeys(self.sku, self.name), indexed=True, repeated=True)
```

makekeys creates a list of the two parameters, so nothing special.

doing the following:

```
query = cls.query()
data = query.fetch(projection=[Pricelist.sku_name])
for d in data:
    logging.info(d.sku_name)
```

gets only the first value in d.sku_name and not all values of the list of the ComputedProperty.

```
# result with projection
[u'0300022']
```

Doing the same without the projection all values of sku_name are available as a list.

```
# result without projection but the full data record
[u'0300022', u'sbrpgznplus100']
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/projectionqueries:

> Projecting a property with multiple values will not populate all
>   values for that property. Instead, a separate entity will be returned
>   for each unique combination of projected values matching the query.

Comment: That does not really answer the question. I have only one property which is repeated and not multiple properties.

Comment: It says, "A (singular) property with multiple values (for the singular property)"

Comment: Yep OK, but it does not work, or at least I do not see how to access the values in the projection.

Comment: Have to check it with the software. But now I see what you mean

Comment: Thanks for the hint. With 509 records I really get 712 records back from the query with the projection. So every key is listed.